# Building geocanvas native extension fails

Tags: ruby, rubygems, fedora

I am searching around for similar issues but I could not find a solution that I have not implemented yet:

I have installed ruby and gems but something is wrong and I cannot update the packages.

```
$ yum install gcc gcc-c++ ruby ruby-devel rubygems

Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Package gcc-4.8.2-7.fc20.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gcc-c++-4.8.2-7.fc20.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package ruby-2.0.0.353-16.fc20.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package ruby-devel-2.0.0.353-16.fc20.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package rubygems-2.1.11-115.fc20.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Ruby version:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]
```

I paste the message appearing for goocanvas, updating as root:

```
Updating goocanvas
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing goocanvas:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for -Wall option to compiler... yes
checking for -Waggregate-return option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wcast-align option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wextra option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wformat=2 option to compiler... yes
checking for -Winit-self option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wlarger-than-65500 option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-declarations option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-format-attribute option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-include-dirs option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-noreturn option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-prototypes option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wnested-externs option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wold-style-definition option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wpacked option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wpointer-arith option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wswitch-default option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wswitch-enum option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wundef option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wwrite-strings option to compiler... yes
checking for rb_define_alloc_func() in ruby.h... yes
checking for rb_block_proc() in ruby.h... yes
checking for new allocation framework... yes
checking for attribute assignment... no
checking for rb_errinfo() in ruby.h... yes
checking for cairo... yes
checking for rb_cairo.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib64
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-override-variables
    --without-override-variables


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/share/gems/gems/pango-2.1.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/share/gems/gems/pango-2.1.0/ext/pango/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Do you have [Pango](http://www.pango.org/) installed?

Comment: Yes, it is installed: `pango-1.36.1-2.fc20.x86_64` PS: Thank you for the corrections.

Comment: What about [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/)? And did you look at the log that’s referenced (`/usr/local/share/gems/gems/pango-2.1.0/ext/pango/gem_make.out`)? You should include it here (unless it’s just the same as what’s included in the output already here).

Comment: Yes, it is the same. However, the packages that have to be updated and present the relevant error are the following: `goocanvas (1.2.6 < 2.1.0)
gstreamer (2.0.2 < 2.1.0)
gtk2 (2.0.2 < 2.1.0)
pango (2.0.2 < 2.1.0)
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that those gems were installed through fedora repository.

Uninstalling with yum and reinstalling with gem, did the trick.

Comment: In general, always use RubyGems to install gems rather than an OS package manager (be it yum, apt, etc.).